# How to set a splash screen in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, splash-screen

How to do this? Can anyone help?

Maybe the answer is simpler than I thought I just didn't think about it.

I was trying to drag and drop [to replace the second logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fQis.png), but it doesn't seem to work. It just refuses to replace the image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't **remove** the Unity Splash, if you only have the personal license. (The checkbox is grayed out)

But you can show your Logo, either after the Unity Logo ("All Sequential") or at the same time ("Unity Logo Below"):

[image]

The restrictions for personal license can be found here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsSplashScreen.html

Comment: I don't want to remove it. I want to add mine, but it doesn't let me overwrite the current one.

Comment: I chose "Sprite (2D and UI)" in the Import settings for the Logo file. Maybe that's what is stopping you from dragging it into the Logos slot?

Answer (score 0):

another option is to just make a bunch of mico scenes and add them to build index. This way you can add Audio, animations and other things to it if you like. The build ion Unity on, unless you have the pro version, forces you to have the default lame 'Made By Unity' splash but that doesn't mean you cannot write your own.

Try this out:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;

namespace ZeredaGames
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Canvas))]
    public class CustomSplashScreen : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] int splashScreenCount = 1;
        [SerializeField] Text companySignatureText;
        [SerializeField] Image fadeImage;
        [SerializeField] float fadeDuration = 2.135f;

        [SerializeField] bool addSound;
        [SerializeField] AudioClip splashAudioClip;
        AudioSource source;

        [SerializeField] bool addAnimation;
        Animator animator;
        [SerializeField] RuntimeAnimatorController animatorController;
        [SerializeField] string runAnimationStateName = "Animate";
        private void Awake()
        {
            if (animator == null && addAnimation)
            {
                if (GetComponent<Animator>() == null)
                    animator = gameObject.AddComponent<Animator>();
                else
                    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
                if (animatorController != null)
                    animator.runtimeAnimatorController = animatorController;
            }
            if (source == null && addSound)
            {
                if(GetComponent<AudioSource>() == null)
                    source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
                else
                    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
                if (source.clip == null)
                    source.clip = splashAudioClip;
            }
            if (fadeImage != null) StartFade();
            else
            {
                fadeImage =  GameObject.Find("FadeImage").GetComponent<Image>();
                StartFade();
            }
        }
        void StartFade()
        {
            if (fadeImage != null)
                FadeOutText(companySignatureText, 0);
            FadeInImage(fadeImage, 0);
            FadeOutImage(fadeImage, fadeDuration);
            StartCoroutine(RunSplash(fadeDuration));
        }
        IEnumerator RunSplash(float startWaitTime)
        {
            if (addAnimation)
                animator.Play(runAnimationStateName);

            if (fadeImage != null)
                FadeInText(companySignatureText, startWaitTime);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWaitTime);

            if (addSound)
            {
                source.Play();
                yield return new WaitWhile(() => source.isPlaying == false);
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWaitTime);

            FadeInImage(fadeImage, startWaitTime);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(startWaitTime);

            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }
        #region Fading Display Message Text
        /// <summary>
        /// Displays a message over time and then disapears
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The Text field to modify</param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="color"></param>
        /// <param name="fadeTimer"></param>
        public static void DisplayFadeMessage(Text text, string message, Color color, float fadeTimer)
        {
            FadeInText(text, 0);
            text.color = color;
            text.text = message;
            FadeOutText(text, fadeTimer);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Displays a message over time and then disapears
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The Text field to modify</param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="color"></param>
        /// <param name="fadeTimer"></param>
        public static void DisplayFadeMessage(TMP_Text text, string message, Color color, float fadeTimer)
        {
            FadeInText(text, 0);
            text.color = color;
            text.text = message;
            FadeOutText(text, fadeTimer);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Fades out an Text over time. [Make full invisable]
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The text used to fade.</param>
        /// <param name="fadeLength">How long it fades to alpha 0.</param>
        static void FadeOutText(Text text, float fadeLength)
        {
            text.CrossFadeAlpha(0.0f, fadeLength, false);
            if (text.color.a == 0)
                text.text = "";
        }
        static void FadeOutText(TMP_Text text, float fadeLength)
        {
            text.CrossFadeAlpha(0.0f, fadeLength, false);
            if (text.color.a == 0)
                text.text = "";
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Fades in an Text over time. [Make full visable]
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text">The text used to fade.</param>
        /// <param name="fadeLength">How long it fades to alpha 1.</param>
        static void FadeInText(Text text, float fadeLength)
        {
            text.CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, fadeLength, false);
        }
        static void FadeInText(TMP_Text text, float fadeLength)
        {
            text.CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, fadeLength, false);
        }
        #endregion Fading Display Message Text
        #region Fading Image
        /// <summary>
        /// Fades out an image over time. [Make full invisable]
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="FadeImage">The Image used to fade.</param>
        /// <param name="fadeLength">How long it fades to alpha 0.</param>
        public static void FadeOutImage(Image image, float fadeLength)
        {
            image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            image.CrossFadeAlpha(0.0f, fadeLength, false);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Fades in an image over time. [Make full visable]
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="FadeImage">The Image used to fade.</param>
        /// <param name="fadeLength">How long it fades to alpha 1.</param>
        public static void FadeInImage(Image image, float fadeLength)
        {
            image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            image.CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, fadeLength, false);
        }
        #endregion Fading Image
    }
}
```

Comment: "The build ion Unity on" => With the build in Unity one*\

Comment: Don't comment to update your answer. Instead, [edit].